# LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_support

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I use Capistrano to deploy my app. Ruby is installed by RVM on my Mac, on the server is same Ruby version (2.2.5) installed by rbenv.

After I want to cap production deploy, the following error appears:

```
SSHKit::Command::Failed: rake exit status: 1
rake stdout: Nothing written
rake stderr: rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_support
/home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails.rb:5:in `require'
/home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
/home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/app/releases/20160606092956/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
/home/user/app/releases/20160606092956/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/app/releases/20160606092956/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/user/app/releases/20160606092956/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)

 DEBUG [0ac2a446]   Bundled gems are installed into /home/user/app/shared/bundle.
  INFO [0ac2a446] Finished in 0.509 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG [d7061392] Running if test ! -d /home/user/app/releases/20160606043027; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/user/app/releases/2016060604…
 DEBUG [d7061392] Command: if test ! -d /home/user/app/releases/20160606043027; then echo "Directory does not exist '/home/user/app/releases/201606060…
 DEBUG [d7061392] Finished in 0.036 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
  INFO [b8dc48fb] Running bundle exec rake assets:precompile as user@52.28.250.42
 DEBUG [b8dc48fb] Command: cd /home/user/app/releases/20160606043027 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" ; bundle exec rake assets:precompile )
 DEBUG [b8dc48fb]   rake aborted!
 DEBUG [b8dc48fb]   LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_support
 DEBUG [b8dc48fb]   /home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails.rb:5:in `require'
/home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `require'
/home/user/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.1.14/lib/rails/all.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/app/releases/20160606043027/config/application.rb:3:in `require'
/home/user/app/releases/20160606043027/config/application.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/app/releases/20160606043027/Rakefile:4:in `require'
/home/user/app/releases/20160606043027/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.2.5/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
 DEBUG [b8dc48fb]   (See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

This is deploy.rb:

```
lock '3.5.0'

set :application, "app_#{fetch(:stage)}"

set :repo_url, 'git@bitbucket.org:...'

set :user, 'user'

server "ip_adress", user: fetch(:user), roles: %w(app db web)

set :deploy_to, "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/#{fetch(:application)}"

# Default value for :pty is false
# set :pty, true

set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push("config/database.yml")
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', 'public/system')

set :bundle_flags, '--deployment'
set :bundle_jobs, 4

set :keep_assets, 2

set :use_sudo, true

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, "2.2.5"

set :rails_env, fetch(:stage)

set :passenger_restart_with_touch, true

namespace :deploy do
  after :restart, :clear_cache do
    on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
      # Here we can do anything such as:
      # within release_path do
      #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
      # end
    end
  end

end
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.14'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.18'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
# gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'sass'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'
gem "therubyracer"
gem "less-rails"

# UI
gem 'nprogress-rails'
gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"
gem "simple-navigation"
gem 'autosize-rails'
gem "emoticons_helper"

### Autentication
gem "devise"
gem 'cancancan', '~> 1.10'

gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "omniauth-linkedin"

# utils
gem  "quiet_assets"
gem 'social-share-button'

gem 'dragonfly', '~> 1.0.12'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring

# gem "thin"

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-modal-rails'

gem "capistrano", "~> 3.5.0"

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-rails', require: false
  gem 'capistrano-passenger', require: false
  gem 'byebug'
end

gem "activesupport", "~> 4.1.14"


# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

The server is Amazon EC2 with Ubuntu, Ruby 2.2.5 (installed by rbenv).

Is this the error with gem active_support, or am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Delete your Gemfile.lock file and try to run bundle update and then bundle install again. I hope it works for you.

Comment: @DineshSaini I`ve tried this solution before and now again. But still the same error :-(

Comment: @DineshSaini Just to clarify, it is good to install gems and use their version. Because if you delete Gemfile.lock, you can damage your gems. So for example use gem "devise", '~> 3.5.6', not just gem "devise".

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you are doing anything wrong. My guess is that you've encountered a bug in Bundler, or there is a file permissions issue that is preventing the ActiveSupport gem from being loaded.

Check these things:

1. Verify that ActiveSupport is indeed installed in `/home/ubuntu/jozu_production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems`. You should see a directory named `activesupport-4.1.14`, owned by your `ubuntu` user. Make sure the directory and its contents are all owned by `ubuntu` and are readable.
2. Make sure you have the latest version of Bundler installed in your rbenv-managed Ruby 2.2.5 environment. As of this writing, that is Bundler 1.12.5. (Run `gem install bundler`.)
3. Try manually running the precompile command on the server to see if there is any difference in behavior. Add `--trace` to the command to get additional troubleshooting data.

   ```
   cd /home/ubuntu/jozu_production/releases/20160606043027 && ( export RAILS_ENV="production" ; bundle exec rake assets:precompile --trace )
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to require `activesupport` for a Ruby project using the command below:

```
require 'active_support/time'
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

All I had to do was to install the rails gem into the project using the command below:

```
gem install rails
```

After that the `require 'active_support/time'` worked fine.